QDockWidget Dock location
I have developed a PyQt app that correctly calls a QDockWidget and allows it to be floatable. All is well.
I can store the floating position and size of the Dock. What I can not see how to do is find out where the DockWidget is when docked. The isFloating() only tells me if it is floating. But I see no method to find where it is when docked.
I wish to use this data to show() the dock after being hidden. If it was docked but hidden() - which dock location (there can be four!) was it in? I could store such data in a QSetting, but I do not know the query to find where it goes - and in part how to unhide it in the dock location.
Studying the PyQt documentation for QDockWidget provides no clue. But maybe this is in the QMainWindow?

QMainWindow.dockWidgetArea().

I see - now my QDockWidget need to signal(call) QMainWindow to get the value and then store it.  Bit of go up a level to tell the lower level what is what.  This is doable - just a bit confusing and does not seem Pythonic.

Well, first of all, you need to remember that PyQt (and even PySide) is a python binding to an external library, meaning that you must compromise between "Pythonic-ism" and effectiveness; some paradigms may not even work in Python, even if they make sense within their context. Then, as much as OOP concepts may go, a dock widget may only know about its "dock position" by querying its parent (which may be none, irrelevant or inconsistent). The QMainWindow API is certainly not perfect as we may hope, but that's how it works; besides, "pythonic" is not an absolute rule: it's not even a rule.
